# Setting the page title of Chrome window.open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have some JavaScript that is being used to open a new window and display a PDF file. This is working fine apart from the title of the new window being open. I am using the window.open function and I have set the title of the page using the document.write function (see code below). The code works fine for FF and IE but for some reason Google Chrome just displays 'Untitled - Google Chrome'

```
<body>
    <a href="javascript:openNewWindow();">Click Here</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openNewWindow()
        {
            var pdfWindow = window.open('', "window",
                'resizable=1,scrollbars=0,width=800,height=600');

            pdfWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Window Title</title></head>');

            pdfWindow.document
                    .write('<body><iframe src="" id="ifrm" name="ifrm" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>');

            pdfWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

            pdfWindow.document.close();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Note: I have also tried adding - pdfWindow.document.title="Title"; - to the JavaScript, with no luck.

Is there anything specific that is required for Chrome or am I just missing something??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Works for me when I set the 1st parameter of open() to `'about:blank'`

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the url in the first parameter, like "about:blank":

```
window.open('about:blank', "window", 'resizable=1,scrollbars=0,width=800,height=600');
```

Comment: The spec clearly says that an empty string will assume "about:blank". in fact it even says that ANY value there will open a window on about:blank, and AFTER the script block that opened the window has finished, the url, if valid, will be loaded. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open#Description chrome is just buggy with window.open() because of google messing up with the popup blocker and limiting how window.open() runs in different scopes.

Answer (score 0):

It will work on Chrome in incognito mode. So the issue is caused by an extension, probablly adblock. Disabling the extensions will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The pop up dialogue/window was blocked by chrome browser by default. If you change settings, that will do.

Comment: Which settings in particular?