# Displaying a new browser window from flash on Chrome

Tags: flash, google-chrome

I am trying to open a browser window with a specific URL from within flash.  The code below works on IE and FF but not Chrome.  I see nothing happen and I see no output on chrome's javascript console.  Any help would be appreciated

```
    private function newWin():void {

        var jscommand:String = "window.open('http://www.slashdot.org','win','height=200,width=300,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes')";
        var urlX:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:" + jscommand + ";");
        ExternalInterface.call("window.open","http://www.slashdot.org","win","height=200,width=300,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes");

    }
    ]]></fx:Script>

     <s:Button label="Go to adobe.com 5"
               click="newWin()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

With your JS command, you have to change your embed/object HTML tag's "**allowScriptAccess**" attr to "**always**".

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a Flash + Chrome issue, but rather a Javascript + Chrome one.

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994063/setting-the-page-title-of-chrome-window-open), try putting `'about:blank'` as the first param in your javascript, just to see if it opens:

```
window.open('about:blank','win' ...
```

[This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572333/google-chrome-window-open-workaround) may give you some other ideas as well.

If all else fails you can still open a window using [NavigateToURL()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29)

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.slashdot.org"), "_blank");
```

This of course wouldn't give you your window sizing options, but at least you'd get a new window out of it.