# window.open not working with Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to open 2 pages with one click of a link, and this is what I have so far:

```
<a onclick="download()" href="?event=thanks&dl=<?php echo $_GET['dl']; ?>"><?php echo $linkname ?></a>
```

and the Javascript function:

```
function download() {
    newwindow=window.open('http://www.google.com','download','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
```

The code above works perfectly with FireFox and Safari, but it fails to open a new window with Google Chrome. Why is this? My thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: see [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572333/google-chrome-window-open-workaround) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994063/setting-the-page-title-of-chrome-window-open)

Comment: Check the Console in Chrome’s Inspector. That’ll notify you of any errors.

Comment: It may not like the implied global variable `newwindow` in the above code, have you explicitly declared it in a higher scope anywhere else in the script? If not, and you don't need to keep the reference to the created window, try simply prefixing the first line of the JS function with `var`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a>` elements have a download attribute in HTML5 as explained here, with a default value of "" (an empty string).

This means that download === this.download in the onclick handler (this is the element in onevent attributes), and therefore the download attribute of the element is superior to the download property of window.

Oh, what a nightmare. Your function should not named download(). Change your function name to download1() and change your onclick to download1() too

Comment: Sorry, why would this make any difference whatsoever based on the above code?

Comment: I think chrome has default function download for itself and because of this , the above code is not working as the user tries to call download function

Comment: Chrome does not have a global member called `download`, nothing does unless you create one.

Comment: in html5 `a` element has an attribute named download. I edited my post look at it now

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 download attribute.This attribute will tell browser that virtual link we created is aimed for download only. It will download file from link`s href to file with name specified as download attribute`s value. This feature works with Chrome.
Sample Code:

```
window.downloadFile = function(sUrl) {

    //If in Chrome or Safari - download via virtual link click
    if (window.downloadFile.isChrome || window.downloadFile.isSafari) {
        //Creating new link node.
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = sUrl;

        if (link.download !== undefined){
            //Set HTML5 download attribute. This will prevent file from opening if supported.
            var fileName = sUrl.substring(sUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, sUrl.length);
            link.download = fileName;
        }

        //Dispatching click event.
        if (document.createEvent) {
            var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            e.initEvent('click' ,true ,true);
            link.dispatchEvent(e);
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Force file download (whether supported by server).
    var query = '?download';

    window.open(sUrl + query);
}

window.downloadFile.isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') &gt; -1;
window.downloadFile.isSafari = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') &gt; -1;
```