# document object not available in timer function

Tags: jquery

Im trying to popup an information window in a specific interval. Its working fine when executing alone

```
var w = window.open('', "", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");
    //alert(ICJX_JXPath);
​
 var html = "<h3>Hi</h3>";
​
 $(w.document.body).html(html);
```

But if I execute the same in a timer function it triggers an error something like document is null

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
            var w = window.open('', "", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");
    //alert(ICJX_JXPath);
​
 var html = "<h3>Hi</h3>";
​
 $(w.document.body).html(html);
        },10000);
```

Whats wrong with my timer code

Comment: document.body is accessible in the `setinterval` tag but the peoblem is actually with the returning window object w returning from `window.open` function. which is some times return null thats why i put null `if(w != null)` before the code and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right but this code contains some unexpected text that actually hidden text. it shows in the browser source see the below screenshot:
[image]

After edited that workable code here:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    var w = window.open('', "", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");
    var html = "<h3>Hi</h3>";
    $(w.document.body).html(html);
},10000);
```

Above code not working directly in chrome fix the problem following code:

```
window.open('about:blank', "window", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");
```

**-- Thank you --**

Comment: Still its triggering the error Cannot read property 'document' of null

Comment: THanks it worked. But strange thing is chrome popup blocker was blocking it when opening from Timer. But when opening directly it is not blocking

Comment: @SandeepThomas please review my answer

Comment: follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994063/setting-the-page-title-of-chrome-window-open