# How to make it open up every new window in a Chrome in webbrowser or axwebbrowser?

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, browser, vb.net-2010

So I'd like for all the new windows open up in Chrome. Or in a default browser of the user. I know how to make a tabbed webbrowser, I'm not interested in that.

Like what I exactly want to do is, as an example, when I set youtube to homepage of my own webbroswer, and when clicked on a video, it would open up in Chrome.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335954/how-can-i-make-a-html-a-href-hyperlink-open-a-new-window-using-window-location

Comment: this is for HTML @albert

Comment: So you only want to change Chrome's behavior if clicking on a link? Like [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/rpBwsbkmonU)? I still don't got your question...

Comment: No need to vote down for just not getting it. I want my own VB.NET webbrowser to open up new windows in Chrome instead of IE.. :/

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with this code :

To open a new window and go to your youtube video, write this code :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://" & YouTube Video Link Here)
```

and to open a new window only, write this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://")
```

I Hope My Answer Was Useful To You :)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I need. When I click on a YT video it stills open up in Chrome :( Any ideas?

Comment: I mean, it still opens up in IE, I need it to open up in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You Can also Add the webbroswer control manually  .Aftersome Event Took place  It will create and Show .