# Android Mozilla FireFox not opening page in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, seo, anchor

We have a link that we get from server (Url) and we want to open it in new window. We are using following code to do that:

```
<a class="block img-holder usedsearch-img-holder position-rel no-direct" target="_blank" href='/m@(Url)'>
```

This is working fine but is not opening new window in mozilla firefox. I read similar issue and workaround by using onclick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335954/how-can-i-make-a-html-a-href-hyperlink-open-a-new-window-using-window-location).

Only problem is that bots (especially non-google search engines) might not be able to index these pages. How can we achieve both i.e. open link in all browsers w/o javascript dependency?

Comment: I don't see issue on [my test](https://jsfiddle.net/f38kbycf/). If `href` value is coming from server code, please post whole HTML tag.

Comment: i am testing on mozilla firefox v 56.0, device android,

Comment: Please post whole `a` tag after server rendering. The `href` value might have some invalid characters.

Comment: <a class="listingTxt block text-default no-direct" id="listingTxt" title="Honda City 1.5 S MT" profileid="D1405814" target="_blank" href="/m/used/cars-in-mumbai/honda-city-2011-2014-d1405814/">TestLink</a>

Comment: Link is ok. Go to `about:config` in FireFox browser and [turn on the required setting that you found best match](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1066799)

Comment: Not working. It's already 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158751/discussion-between-maverick-and-amit-bhagat).