# Window.open isn't working for multiple links in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I tested this in FF, work fine but not in Chrome. For single link, I found a hack which is using redirect, but I'm still looking for ways to open multiple links in new tabs in chrome.

http://plnkr.co/edit/zVaEFssH4o4qDycSUNGD?p=preview

```
      $scope.openLinks = function(){
        var urls = '';
        angular.forEach($scope.links, function(item){
            $window.open("redirect.html?" + item.link);

    });

  };
```

worth to mentiion, http://www.rapidlinkr.com/ doesn't work in chrome but working in FF.

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572333/google-chrome-window-open-workaround

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv that doesn't help, I want the links be opened in tab not windows

Comment: As it's written right now, one could understand that you need them to open in new windows, not new tabs. Short answer: built-in pop-up blocker.

Comment: For new _tab_ just use `target="_blank"` on the link.

Comment: Also, a decent browser should, and will, block links opened through JavaScript - obvious pop-up spam.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv target="_blank" do nothing

Answer (score 3):

Your `window.open` seems to be working fine in Google Chrome, except for that fact that Chrome's pop-up blocker is blocking the new windows from opening up. There is no way to bypass this as far as I know unless the user allows the pop-up blocker to allow pop-ups on your website.

Comment: I edited my question, actually I want it to be opened in tab, not as pop up windows.

Comment: Window.open should open your links in new tab, not windows (unless explicitly specified). Its the pop-up blocker that is blocking the new tabs from opening.

Comment: I did try it earlier. Firefox opens all 3 tabs for me, but Chrome only opens a single tab of Google, other 2 get blocked by the pop-up blocker shown by a white sign with a red cross on the right side of the address bar in the tab where your demo was open.

Comment: even though user allow that, then the link don't open in new tab, it became pop up windows, which I found annoying..

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible as far as I know.

Comment: what if I use setInterval to open the link 1 by 1?

Comment: but this work like a charm : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclump/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Chirag Bhatia, you can be opened, but you have to allow pop-ups.

[image]

Browsers don't allow you to open multiple pages at the same time, but you can open multiple pages at a time interval. for example at least in javascript it would be like this:

```
     async function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
    async function load() {
        let links = [
            "https://www.google.com/",
            "https://www.facebook.com/",
            "https://www.youtube.com/",
            "https://www.instagram.com/",
            "https://www.twitter.com/",
            "https://www.linkedin.com/",
            "https://www.pinterest.com/",
            "https://www.github.com/",
            "https://www.quora.com/",
            "https://www.reddit.com/"
        ];
        for (const link of links) {
            window.open(link, "_blank");
            await sleep(100);
            console.log("Open another tab");
            console.log(link)
        }
    }
    load();
```