# window.open always opens as blank new window no matter what the link

Tags: javascript

simply using window.open works for everything ive tested in IE, however when it comes to Google Chrome, the exact code just opens up a blank new tab.

ive tried these combinations:

- Network Drives 
  **window.open("\\\\Server\\Data\\NewFolder\\Video.mp4");**
- Local Drives    Network Drives 
  **window.open("C:\\NewFolder\\Video.mp4");**
- Chromes way of file viewing: **window.open("file:///C://NewFolder//Video.mp4")**

am I doing something wrong here or does Chrome have its own way of opening and displaying files?

what I want to happen is for Chrome to either play the .mp4 file itself or open it in Windows Media Player but neither happens.

cheers for any help

if I was to type in *file:///C:/NewFolder/Video.mp4* then this would play the file in chrome. using window.open does absolutely nothing other than display **about:blank**. it will however open a web url but not a file on my computer or a server

Comment: What happens if you manually browse to any of those locations in Chrome?  Also, does anything show up in the browser console?

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572333/google-chrome-window-open-workaround

Comment: can you show your full code ?

Comment: the 2 examples are the full code for opening a file in IE, the Chromes way is what is in the URL bar when I drag and drop a video to play. its only a short bit of code itself however chrome is making the extremely difficult

Answer (score 0):

The code below works just fine in Chrome (i.e. invoked directly from a `click` event -- obviously in the real world you bind dynamically, this is just for test purposes). Note that I've simplified the forward slashes: you don't need to double those up.

How are you triggering your call?

JS:

```
function openThing() {
  window.open("file:///c:/newfolder/video.mp4");
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#open" click="openThing(); return false;">Open Thing</a>
```

Comment: trying to get it to work now, using Lightswitch in Visual Studio and they don't make it easy. I have a button that when clicked on triggers the code associated with that button