# alternate method for window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, extjs4

- I have a js function, when I give async as false it opens as new
  window,
- but when i give async as true its showing as pop up
- I need to make the code as async as true, but it should open as new
  window not as pop up
- can you guys tell me how to Make a asynchronous request so that the
  new window willnot load as a popup.
- is there any alternate method for window.open
- providing my code below

  ```
      //
      debugger;
      Ext.Ajax.request({
          async: false,
          url: sports.util.Utils.getContextPath() + '/tabClicks.do',
  ```

Comment: What's the difference between a pop up and a new window?

Comment: Are you talking about whether the popup blocker complains about it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572333/google-chrome-window-open-workaround - I think you may be referring to the window without the toolbar as a 'popout', you have little control over this with JavaScript in chrome.

Comment: You can open the window in the original event and relocate it when you're ready.

Comment: @barmar yes i am talking about popup complaints

Comment: @Halcyon can you update in my code, its confusing

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little bit weird so it's hard to make the adjustment properly but this is gist of it:

```
showNewWindow: function(menu) {
    var me = this,
        newWindowId = sports.util.Utils.randomString(12);

    //
    // Make a synchronous request so that the new window will
    // not load as a popup.
    //
    debugger;
    var popup = sports.util.Utils.openNewWindow('', 'menu', {}, null, null, newWindowId);
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        async: false,
        url: sports.util.Utils.getContextPath() + '/tabClicks.do',
        params: {
            oldWindowId: sports.util.Utils.getWindowName(),
            newWindowId: newWindowId
        },
        success: function() {
            popup.location.href = "/desktop/main";
        },
        scope: me
    });
},
```

Comment: so you wanted to remove showNewWindowSuccess function

Comment: You can do that, just make sure you do the `registerMenuClick` as well.

Comment: `sportds.ut...`? There is an extra `d` there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you posted there, that code as-is is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: can you tell me how to fix the error Uncaught TypeError: sports.util.Utils.openNewWindow is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Popup blockers try to tell when a window is being opened in direct response to a user action or spontaneously by the application. The way they probably do this is by checking whether the function that called `window.open()` was run in response to a user-triggered event like a mouse click.

When you perform a synchronous AJAX request, the function that was triggered by the mouse click is still running when the response arrives and the success function calls `window.open`. So it's considered to be a user-requested window, not a popup.

When you use asynchronous AJAX, the click handler is no longer running when the success function runs. The asynchronous call to `window.open` is considered spontaneous by the browser, so it blocks it.

I don't think there's any way around this, because anything you could do could also be used by everyone else to get around popup blockers, and they would be useless.

Comment: thanks for your reply, will this can be achieved using Halcyon and user3612048 solutions

Comment: I was just about to add to my answer a solution similar to @Halcyon's answer. Give that a try.

Comment: It should be `popup.document.location.href`

Comment: I updated my code and tested, but still i am getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
function openNewWin(name) {
      $.ajax({
          async: false,
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'your url',
          success: function () {
               window.open(name);
          },
          async: false
      });
  }
```

Comment: name is youe page url which you want to open and that passed from code behind

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add code as well as the comments in the code itself 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.