# Chrome can't scroll new tab content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have some javascript code that opens a new tab and fills it with some html like so:

```
var tab = window.open();
tab.document.write(html);
```

For some reason, you can't scroll the content that shows up in the new tab by using the mouse wheel or by clicking the up/down arrows on the scroll bar. You can still scroll the content by clicking and dragging the scroll bar though.

How do I enable scrolling in the new tab?

If it matters, the html content is an asp.net core developer exception page.

It also happens intermittently. About 50% of the time it seems to work correctly.

Comment: Any css being written to the page?

Comment: @jedifans [yes](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/c224a726f9959f95d948d172140d048aea1caadd/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/DeveloperExceptionPage/Views/ErrorPage.css)

Comment: OK so nothing like `overflow: hidden;` being written out. Perhaps inspect the opened tab in chrome's developer tools to find a cause.

Comment: Interesting. Never seen this one, but it is actually reproducible right from console.

Found a reference on similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572333/google-chrome-window-open-workaround