# Google chrome New update 78.0.3904.70 blocked JavaScript window.open()

Tags: javascript

After my last update for Google Chrome 78.0.3904.70 javascript window.open command not working, its just open and vanishing. Most properly the browser is closing the popup. Any one find a solution for this ?
[image]

```
 window.open('http://www.abhilashthomas.com?RequestID=1', 'popup_window', 'width=800,height=700,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,status=1');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome "window.open" workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572333/google-chrome-window-open-workaround)

Comment: Works fine for me, you could try resetting your browser settings?

Comment: it is working fine for me too

Comment: I tested this in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9ek1rc7/), and I think Chrome is just blocking the popup: https://i.postimg.cc/CMW9s9d9/Screenshot-2019-10-31-at-11-58-32.png. I can't imagine why Chrome's latest update would have changed that though.