# window.open with name - google 'search results' page behaves different

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have a series of links, which I want to open in a new window. Once a window is open and a new link is clicked it should reload the window with a new url.

It works fine by providing a specified target (name) to window.open for a series of websites, but somehow after the google search page has been opened it opens up another window.

When I click `Open w3school` and then `Open React` the behaviour is as intended. If I click `Open google search` and then another link it pops up in a new window.

Steps to recreate:

1. Click `Open w3school` opens a new window (intended)
2. Click `Open React` reloads the page in the opened window (intended)
3. Click `Open google search` reloads the page in the opened window (intended)
4. Click `Open w3school` opens a new window (not intended)

The code below illustrates the issue.

Does anyone have an explanation of this behaviour?

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<button onclick="openW3school()">Open w3school</button>
<button onclick="openGoogleSearch()">Open google search</button>
<button onclick="openReact()">Open React</button>

<script>
function openW3school() {
  window.open("https://www.w3schools.com", "mywindow", "popup");
}

function openGoogleSearch() {
  window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript", "mywindow", "popup");
}

function openReact() {
  window.open("https://reactjs.org/", "mywindow", "popup");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this line is not clear to me: _"If I click Open google search and then another link it pops up in a new window."_ .. what do you mean by saying "and then another link it pops up in a new window"? that `window.open` statement will show a new browser window with the google url loaded... and then?

Comment: I tried adding a "Steps to recreate" section to the question. Hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue in Firefox or Chromium browser (Edge), all the pages are opened within the same pop-up (the one originally opened for w3schools) as expected. Unfortunately the code doesn't work in StackSnippet, you can check it at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7k56wm1/).

Comment: Using Chrome version 109 has the issue on my end. I can reproduce the issue by pasting the code in w3schools code editor. (https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default_default

Comment: How about the fiddle I've linked above, does it work correctly for you? (I don't have Chrome at hands right now.)

Comment: I get a `google.com is blocked` in the fiddle you link above, when I click on `Open google search`.

Comment: A pop-up blocker blocks a pop-up on your testing browser? Set it off for testing. As you can see, pop-ups aren't reliable, it's best to use tabs instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it is due the fact that the Google search results page is sent with

```
cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin-allow-popups; report-to="gws"
```

HTTP header (while the other two pages in your sample are not), what presumably tells browser "block ties with openers if they were on different domain (origin)".

According to [Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy) it should have the effect you describe for Google Chrome:

> If a cross-origin document with COOP is opened in a new window, the opening document will not have a reference to it, and the window.opener property of the new window will be null.

It is strange that Firefox does not seem to respect that, although it is presented as compliant there.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I guess there's no way for me to get around that?

Comment: I guess there might be some way **for you** (or tightly controlled audience) to get around that, involving either some local browser preferences overrides (hacks) or proxy on your local network messing with those headers (also hacks). But for unknown audience, I don't think there could be done much about that.

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation would be that some script in the opened page changes its name (`window.name`).

You can verify / deny that if you check `window.name` of the "stray / detached" popup window in the console; if it will not be `mywindow` then you know the cause.

You may also check `window.opener` - if it is null, then it could indicate that given page deliberately broke ties with your page that created the popup.

Comment: It does indeed seems like it clears out the name of the window. `mywindow` becomes and empty string. Any way to get around this?

Comment: And `window.opener` is null.

Comment: See similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572333/google-chrome-window-open-workaround

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the iframe containing the buttons you'll see the sandbox attributes ("sandbox="). It has allow-scripts, allow-popups, allow-same-origin. But it needs "allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" to work with google.

[image]

Why?
If you check the network activity of the blocked google page you'll see the message about why: "the document was blocked from loading in a popup opened by a sandboxed iframe because this document specifies a cross origin opener policy":
[image]

ie. google.com page is sending a Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy HTTP header. You can read about that in the "Learn More" link :

https://web.dev/articles/coop-coep

As far as I can tell from reading it, the google.com page needs an "isolated environment" to prevent "modifications of document.domain". So it sends a Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy Header to enforce this.

But the iframe sandbox will "prevent the content from navigating its top-level browsing context".

Solution?
If you inspect the iframe with the buttons and add "allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" attribute to the iframe, then reload the frame, you can click it and the google pop up will then open properly:

[image]