# popup window on mozilla

Tags: javascript

i'm using javascript to open a new window in a html page. It works fine ie whereas mozilla opens a new tab. is there a way to make the mozilla open the popup in a new window instead of new tab using javascript or any parameter?

-Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab):

Answer (score 1):

No, this behavior is defined by the browser. You can only change it in the browser AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior depends on user-agent configuration.  Nothing you can do.