# Open a new browser window WITHOUT using target="_blank"

Tags: html, browser

Every solution I've seen so far for opening a new browser window uses the target property in  to set it to "_blank". This is frustrating because in some browsers it only opens a new tab AND combine that with the auto-resizing behvaiour at http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?&message=test, it basically mangles my browser whenever I try updating my status from my site.

How can I be sure to open a new window when a user clicks on a link?

### Thanks!

Trindaz on Fedang

Comment: Why do you want to force the user to open a new tab window?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab

Comment: I'm not sure if the question is identical, but I'm pretty sure the answer is still the same: You can't. It's a user controlled browser setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)

function newwindow()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','width=300,height=300');
myWindow.document.write("<p>This should open in a popup</p>");
myWindow.focus();
}
```

Comment: That's a popup, not a new -window- though.

Comment: It's as close as you'll get to bypassing user settings though.

Answer (score 2):

Popups are windows, they just have some features disables. You can make a popup act like a regular window by enabling these features. For example, if you open a popup with

```
window.open('url', 'name', 'width=500, height=500, status=1, toolbar=1, location=1, menubar=1, resizable=1');
```

the window will have a toolbar, a URL bar, a status bar, menus, and it will be resizable. It will the same as any other window.

Keep in mind, however, that many browsers block window.open() under some conditions, and some of them will open new tabs if you specify a lot of features. Some are weird about it too; Chrome, for example, uses scroll bars on popups by default, but if you specifically tell it to use scroll bars in a popup (using scrollbars=1), it will open in a tab instead.

So basically there is no way to be completely sure that your page will always open in a new window, because browsers all handle this stuff differently, users can change settings too. The code above is probably your best bet if you have to have a new window, but you might want to look into other options.

Answer (score 0):

There is a legitimate reason for using Target=_blank that everybody has completely overlooked, and that is when a website is written as a BOOK with chapters/pages and the Table of Contents must remain intact without using the BACK button to reload the previous page (Table of Contents).  This way all a surfer needs to do is close the Target Page when finished reading and they will be back to the Table of Contents.
  Lucky for us that HTML5 has reinstated the Target="_blank" code, but unfortunately the "Block Popups" must be unchecked for it to work.