# javascript window.open

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

How can I open a new window (not a tab!) when I call a window.open function.
That window should not contain an toolbar, or menu options.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
window.open("http://www.google.com",
            "name_your_window",
            "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=no,width=200,height=200,menubar=no,toolbar=no");
```

For a list of the parameters available, see [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/openinga.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You can't override the browser settings to "open all new windows in a tab" in all browsers (thank goodness). This is a duplicate of: [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)