# Javascript form submission doesn't give proper result

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, codeigniter

i have set the form action to a text retrieved from the database which has an id.my problem is when the form action executed it always shows the first id even if i clicked on the text holding id=2.I have checked the page source and it's showing the correct id for all the text.

here is my view code

```
<?php foreach ($content as $cont):?>
<form id="offer" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'index.php/pages/detail'?>">
<input type='hidden' name='cont_id'id='cont_id' value='<?php echo $cont->id?>'>
<a onclick="document.getElementById('offer').submit();"><?php echo $cont->title?></a>
</br>
</form>
<?php endforeach;?>
</div>
<script>
    function submitForm() {
      document.getElementById("offer").submit();}
</script>
```

here is my controller :

```
echo $this->input->post('cont_id');
```

Comment: Try using `window.open`. See on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465653/javascript-window-open

Comment: Search for `javascript form submit()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.submit()`

```
<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('yourFormID').submit();">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have JAVASCRIPT knowledge you can use the

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

method to submit the form..

create a Javascript Function

```
    <script>
             function submitForm() 
             {
                   document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
             }
   </script>
```

use this code for the text you want to hyperlink the button to

```
<h1 onclick="submitForm()">Click on this text</h1>
```