# How can I modify this bookmarklet to work on a tab instead of a new window?

Tags: javascript, popup, bookmarklet

When you put this in your browser it opens a simple notepad to type in.

I don't know enough about javascript to alter it but I would like to make it so it DOESN'T open in a new window but rather in the current window or another tab.

Is this even possible?

```
javascript:pwin=window.open('','_blank','menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,location=no,height=450,width=350');pwin.document.body.contentEditable='true';pwin.document.designMode='on';void(0);if(window.focus){pwin.focus()};
```

Comment: You might like this... http://lifehacker.com/398139/edit-any-web-page-with-a-bookmarklet

Answer (score 2):

Technically, `window.open` *does not* always open in a new window. You can use `_self` instead of `_blank`, and it will open in the same window. Or use `_parent` and it will open in the current frame's parent.

Answer (score 0):

`Window.open` always opens this in a new window. 
Instead I think you can try `window.location`. Not tried tough.

Answer (score 0):

Ok did a little digging and there is nothing you can do that will guarantee that it will open in a new tab.  However if you remove the width and height parameters some browsers will open in a new tab if user preferences haven't overridden this behavior.  See this post (2nd answer in list) [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't looking to open a window, then don't window.open()

Setting window.location should do the trick, as pointed out by Sachin