# How to open webpages in a new tab in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

In my html code there are several link like this:

```
<a href="www.exampe.com" target="_blank">example</a>
```

Is there a way to open these links in a new tab ( and not in a new window ) ?

Comment: Shouldn't that really be up to the user, not the web page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970746/html-how-to-force-open-links-in-a-new-tab

Comment: +1 for +Andrew Barber's answer  - Users decide what they like, and going against that makes for unhappy users...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the preference the user has set in their browser. You might consider adding some text like

> "Hold down the Ctrl key and click the following link"

If the user follows your suggestion, the page will open in a new tab. None of this is optimal.

See [HTML: how to force open links in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3970746/139917) for more.

Answer (score 1):

`target="_blank"` attribute should open that page in a new tab. It probably depends on your browser settings whether the page opens in a new tab or window.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do this, short of a browser plugin.

That is for a reason.  You do not want to take the user somewhere they don't want to be.

They may not want to be in Internet Explorer.

What you SHOULD do is suggest that your website may only be compatible with IE.  This way, the user can only blame themselves if something does not work.  Not ideal, but it's generally accepted practice.

Comment: "Not ideal, but it's generally accepted practice": not a good practice, especially with jQuery available. It makes me very angry when I am forced to use IE for a silly website. Phooey on them! ;-)

Comment: Well, I don't know the OP's original intent.  It may very well be a silly security restraint that they are only allowed to use IE to access a page.  This is not unheard of.