# Open new page in Tab on Internet Explorer 8 with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Using this below

```
window.open('aPage.aspx');
```

and i can open the page in a new Tab with every Browser, except Internet Explorer 8.

I see in this article
[How to open webpages in a new tab in internet explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709073/how-to-open-webpages-in-a-new-tab-in-internet-explorer)
that i can do this with 'target' attribute of tag 'a'.

I need to have this behavior when another page load. So i don't click on a link/button, the page on Tab will open automatically and i need to use javascript.

Any tips to get this work?

Comment: Maybe the popup blocker is causing you problems?

Comment: Popup blocker is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

you may use window.load or jquery $(window).load(function () {}); 
and put your code inside the function. You may use window.open(url,'_blank'); as you mentioned

Comment: Thanks for suggest but i already do this in $(document).ready(function(){}); and it works everywhere except IE8.

Comment: what version of jquery are you using? jQuery 2.x only supports IE 9.0+

Answer (score 0):

As the answers to the example you posted suggest, you cannot change the settings of the browser.  All you can do is add `target="_blank"` to links and `window.open(url,'_blank');` to the javascript open.  This will tell the browser to open in a new window but the browser will honor the user's preference setting to open in a new tab or window.