# change javascript:openWindow to new tab from source of remote page

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to figure something out, i am getting the html source code of remote page and this code contain links like this one below:

```
<a href='javascript:openWindow("index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=156029&tv_id=848&tid=34928&channel=0&tmpl=component&layout=popup&Itemid=335","735","820")'  >Link#1</a>
```

I want to edit such link before echo it to on my page to make it open in new tab not in new window.

i getting the remote page source with file get content as below:

```
<?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "http://remote.com/static/section0.html";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html

    $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tbody');

    $toRemove = array();

    // gather a list of tbodys to remove
    foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'desktop') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;    

            foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'Recommended') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;  

    // remove them
    foreach($toRemove as $tbody)
      $tbody->parentNode->removeChild($tbody);

    echo str_replace('</h3><table','<table',$doc->saveHTML());
?>
```

as you see i also doing some other editation on the code but i cant transform open new window to new tab

any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about a new browser tab or a new tab on your website?

Comment: @Pitchinnate offcourse new browser tab

Comment: You can't force a new tab that is up to the browser

Comment: Here is a question discussing that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970746/html-how-to-force-links-to-open-in-a-new-tab-not-new-window