# Open two links in different new tabs, not in the same

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have two links in my page with `target="_blank"`, but if i open the first link in a new tab, when i click in the second, the page loads in tha tab that the first link are already open, i need to make they open in different tabs, not in the same. Thanks.

Add the code...

```
<ul style="float: left;">
    <li><a href='{external link}' target="_blank"><span>Help Desk</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='{external link}' target="_blank"><span>Bússola</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML you are using?

Comment: Did you check in different browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`target="_blank"` is the correct (and possibly the only) way to do this but how it behaves depends on the browser and browser settings.

See [HTML: how to force links to open in a new tab, not new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970746/html-how-to-force-links-to-open-in-a-new-tab-not-new-window/18764547#18764547) for more details.

A workaround might be to give them different names like so:

```
<ul style="float: left;">
    <li><a href='{external link}' target="a"><span>Help Desk</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='{external link}' target="b"><span>Bússola</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

That should force the browser to open two new tabs and if you click the first link, then always the same frame will reload (same for the second tab).

Answer (score 1):

Try with javascript function like this

**Html:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="open_win()">Target</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
function open_win() 
{
window.open("https://www.google.co.in/");
}
</script>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18764547/1428854