# submit form in new tab

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in HTML.

```
<form action="xyz.jsp" id="myForm" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" id="param1" name="param1" value="val1">
    <input type="hidden" id="param2" name="param2" value="val2">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="mySubmit">
</form>
```

When submit button is clicked, new page opens in `New Tab`. But when I add code to submit form pragmatically, then the new page is opened in `New Window` instead of `New Tab`. Below is my code to submit form using javascript.

```
<script>
function SubmitForm() {
    document.forms["myForm"].submit();
}
</script>
```

And I am calling this function on `onload` event:

```
<body onload="SubmitForm();">
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970746/html-how-to-force-links-to-open-in-a-new-tab-not-new-window

Answer (score -1):

Try to trigger button click in the method SubmitForm

```
function SubmitForm() {
    $('#mySubmit').click();
}
```

or try onSubmit window.open('xyz.jsp', '_blank') by passing your params

Hope it helps

Comment: The question is tagged with javascript, not jquery

Comment: @Khaleel Thanks for the answer, I tried both approaches, but none of them worked, result is the same.