# open a new HTML tap in Chrome with a specific width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, window

I have a code that opens a new window with specific height and width. I would prefer, if possible, to open a new tab instead of a new window, but still being able to specify the height and width of the new tab. Is that possible?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick='var myW=window.open

("http://www.google.com/", "mywindow", "width = " + window.screen.width + ", height = " + window.screen.width / 3 + "");'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can you resize new tab? The tab takes full height and width of the window.

Comment: I think you have a point, to make the tab the size I want, I guess i would have to start making the first window that size. If so, would the following tabs would have the same size as the parent window?

Comment: I think that you can do one thing - Open the link in new tab (in the existing window) and then resize the existing window.

Comment: yes, I think that should work too, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know it is not possible to decide if a new link is opened only in tab. The settings of the browser decide if a new clicked link `target="_blank"` is opend in a tab or window.
for sure its possible to force with javascript to open a new window and not tab.

**Existing Questions:**

*about forcing open in a new Tab:*
[HTML: how to force links to open in a new tab, not new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970746/html-how-to-force-links-to-open-in-a-new-tab-not-new-window)

*Resize windows with Javascript:*
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp

Answer (score 1):

you can replace `myWindow.resizeTo(250, 250);` number to change window size

```
<p>Open a new window, and resize the width and height to 500px:</p>
<button onclick="openWin()">Create window</button>
<button onclick="resizeWin()">Resize window</button>

<script>
var myWindow;
function openWin() {
  myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=100, height=100");
}
function resizeWin() {
  myWindow.resizeTo(250, 250);
  myWindow.focus();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are right, thank you, but it is not what I'm looking for. When the new window is created, it has the right size already, my issue is that I would prefer to open a new tab because some browsers block the pop ups and a new tab is more friendly