# Automatic opening of a new page when closing it

Tags: html

I would like to make sure that when someone closes my website page, they will automatically open it in a new tab, as you have probably seen in some annoying ads. please help me.

Comment: Impossible. If this was allowed it would be abused such that you would never be able to leave a webpage, since it could just reopen it when it detects the window `onbeforeunload` event.

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately not possible as the browser contains the settings associated with this behavior.

Here is a link to a similar question [HTML: how to force links to open in a new tab, not new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970746/html-how-to-force-links-to-open-in-a-new-tab-not-new-window)