# How to retrieve GET parameters from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, get

Consider:

```
http://example.com/page.html?returnurl=%2Fadmin
```

For `js` within `page.html`, how can it retrieve `GET` parameters?

For the above simple example, `func('returnurl')` should be `/admin`.

But it should also work for complex query strings...

Comment: You might want to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location for the properties of the `Location` object.

Comment: Here's a one liner to get all params as a keyed object: `let getParamsObject = ([...(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search))]).reduce((prev,curr)=>(Object.assign(prev,{[curr[0]]:curr[1]})),{})`

Comment: This is how MDN solves this:
`let params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
let name = params.get("name"); // is the string "Jonathan"`
from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get

Answer (score 483, accepted):

With the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object. This code gives you GET without the question mark.

```
window.location.search.substr(1)
```

From your example it will return `returnurl=%2Fadmin`

**EDIT**: I took the liberty of changing [Qwerty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21210643/179669), which is **really good**, and as he pointed I followed exactly what the OP asked:

```
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
        tmp = [];
    location.search
        .substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .forEach(function (item) {
          tmp = item.split("=");
          if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
        });
    return result;
}
```

I removed the duplicated function execution from his code, replacing it a variable ( tmp ) and also I've added [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent), exactly as OP asked. I'm not sure if this may or may not be a security issue.

Or otherwise with plain for loop, which will work even in IE8:

```
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
        tmp = [];
    var items = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
    for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        tmp = items[index].split("=");
        if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It should also work for complex query strings...

Comment: It will return all of the get query regardless of the size, but it will be one loooong string.

Comment: For `returnurl` it should be `/admin`...

Comment: This answer is completely wrong by both question definition and implementation. So if you are going to return the whole querystring anyways, which is not what the asker asked, you should use `location.search.substr(1)` at least.

Comment: I like it. I like the plain `for` version too. Changed my downvote. Anyway, the reason why I suggested `substr`, `substring` or `slice` `(1)` is because there is unnecessary task of reading and searching the ? in `replace()`.

Comment: @Qwerty I changed to substring - there might be a question mark inside the query string ( even escaped - %3F )

Comment: What is your experience - is `forEach` supported in more or less all browsers used currently? Or should one better use the `for` version to be on the safe side?

Comment: @PediT.- it depends what are the requirements for support. If you want to use the newest features use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: @PediT. https://caniuse.com/#search=forEach

Comment: Why continue looping through all GET parameters when the searched parameter has already been found? In the for() version, I would put a return directly in the if() clause inside of the loop.    
=> This is also why I prefer the for() loop in this case: there's no way of stopping a foreach() loop ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description )

Comment: if the parameter contains "=" character this method fails. Instead you should now your parameter names and parse according to names ie: split("{}=".format($param_name))...

Comment: @EmreBayram: Good point. How about so: `let key = item.split('=', 1)[0]; let value = item.includes('=') ? item.replace(/^[^=]+=/, '') : '1';` This will set the value '1' in case of there being no '=' at all and also handle multiple '='s at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for findGetParameter() function, it saves me

Comment: This answer is obsolete.  As of 2022, vanilla JS should be used instead, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39620299/1353549.

Comment: @akim the answer is 11 years old. It is as vanilla as it could be. There many new APIs now.

Comment: @Bakudan Your answer was perfect in its time, and I did not mean to give the impression I find it "wrong".  My comment is strictly about the order in which the answers are reported.  Today the answers based on the JS std lib should be first.  Cheers!

Answer (score 283):

`window.location.search` will return everything from the ? on.  This code below will remove the ?, use split to separate into key/value arrays, then assign named properties to the *params* object:

```
function getSearchParameters() {
    var prmstr = window.location.search.substr(1);
    return prmstr != null && prmstr != "" ? transformToAssocArray(prmstr) : {};
}

function transformToAssocArray( prmstr ) {
    var params = {};
    var prmarr = prmstr.split("&");
    for ( var i = 0; i < prmarr.length; i++) {
        var tmparr = prmarr[i].split("=");
        params[tmparr[0]] = tmparr[1];
    }
    return params;
}

var params = getSearchParameters();
```

You can then get the *test* parameter from `http://myurl.com/?test=1` by calling `params.test`.

Comment: @Bakudan `for...in` is when you are working with objects.  With arrays the for loop is preferred, see [this question on `for...in` with arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

Comment: It doesn't hurt much, but point taken. For reasons that are explained here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/120362 , though, I won't return `null`, but the empty `{}` Object.

Comment: Maybe you should make this a function and insert: if (prmstr == "") { return null; } at line 2. Otherwise if there's no '?' in the URL you end up with a 'params' set to Object {: undefined}, which is weird.

Comment: @weltraumpirat, I was actually on my way to edit my comment to suggest  returning {} instead and I didn't see your reply. In any case thanks for updating your code :)

Comment: I have adapted your wonderful code to allow for situations like `?q=abc&g[]=1&g[]=2` to become an assoc array with 2 params: q & g where g is an Array with 2 values. https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/11372570

Comment: heads-up to anyone reading this: some older applications separate parameters with a semicolon rather than an ampersands.

Comment: `prmstr != null && prmstr != ""` is redundant. Unless you use !== for type specific comparison, you can just shorten that to `!prmstr`.

Answer (score 173):

You should use URL and URLSearchParams native functions:

```js
let url = new URL("https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=mdn%20query%20string")
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
let sourceid = params.get('sourceid') // 'chrome-instant'
let q = params.get('q') // 'mdn query string'
let ie = params.has('ie') // true
params.append('ping','pong')

console.log(sourceid)
console.log(q)
console.log(ie)
console.log(params.toString())
console.log(params.get("ping"))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams
https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/features/

Comment: Unfortunately this is not compatible with IE :'(

Comment: Add the polyfill listed below the code snippet to patch IE and turn that frown upside down.

Comment: In case you are looking something similar with >IE5 support and basic XSS prevention 
[I wrote a small gist](https://gist.github.com/DimitrK/ece75318efbfce2605bfcf1a035f1472) .

Comment: `new URLSearchParams("https://www.google.com/webhp?q=mdn%20query%20string")` doesn't work

Comment: @Alexey > because it should be that `var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search.slice(1));`

Comment: thanks, ok @RaphaëlGonçalves

Comment: This [doesn't work on iOS Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility), which is a much larger market share than IE is.

Comment: @Xeoncross Support has been added to iOS Safari and all other modern browsers except IE

Comment: This is strongest answer without using invented functions and tons of codes

Comment: The best answer! Thank you so much! It works with Safari 13.1.2, Chrome 84.0 and Firefox 79.0.

Comment: You should use `let params = url.searchParams;` instead of `let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);`

Answer (score 160):

## *tl;dr* solution on a single line of code using vanilla JavaScript

```
var queryDict = {}
location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1]})
```

This is the **simplest solution**. It unfortunately **does not** handle multi-valued keys and encoded characters.

```
"?a=1&a=%2Fadmin&b=2&c=3&d&e"
> queryDict
a: "%2Fadmin"  // Overridden with the last value, not decoded.
b: "2"
c: "3"
d: undefined
e: undefined
```

### *Multi-valued keys* and *encoded characters*?

See the original answer at *[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript/21152762#21152762)*.

```
"?a=1&b=2&c=3&d&e&a=5&a=t%20e%20x%20t&e=http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dståle%26car%3Dsaab&a=%2Fadmin"
> queryDict
a: ["1", "5", "t e x t", "/admin"]
b: ["2"]
c: ["3"]
d: [undefined]
e: [undefined, "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab"]
```

---

In your example, you would access the value like this:

```
"?returnurl=%2Fadmin"
> qd.returnurl    // ["/admin"]
> qd['returnurl'] // ["/admin"]
> qd.returnurl[0] // "/admin"
```

Comment: Seems to be the best answer here.

Comment: Thank you for noticing my error. I also took the liberty of modifying your code, removing the second split invocation, which can be replaced with a local variable.

Comment: Short and easy to understand :)

Comment: what is vanilla? another js injected? @NaveedHasan

Comment: @NaveedHasan VanillaJS is a term originating from a joke name for pure javascript without additional libraries. [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435653/what-is-vanillajs)

Comment: You can add decodeURIComponent() to this: `var queryDict = {};
location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item.split("=")[1])}); queryDict`

Answer (score 43):

A more fancy way to do it: :)

```
var options = window.location.search.slice(1)
                      .split('&')
                      .reduce(function _reduce (/*Object*/ a, /*String*/ b) {
                        b = b.split('=');
                        a[b[0]] = decodeURIComponent(b[1]);
                        return a;
                      }, {});
```

Comment: Fancy indeed, but watch out reduce is not compatible with all browsers. More info here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094935/ie-js-reduce-on-an-object

Comment: Notably it's not supported in IE8

Comment: If there is an url as a parameter, the decodeURIComponent will mistakenly resolve it as another &key=val pairs.

Comment: As Qwerty has pointed out: decodeURIComponent should be moved inside: a[b[0]] = decodeURIComponent(b[1])

Comment: Thanks, I like this a lot - if IE is not dead, IE8 definitely is.
Thing I would improve are handling empty parameters (without the `=value` part) and the same parameter multiple times (maybe use a list). And possibly it would be safer to use `Object.create(null)` instead of `{}`.

Answer (score 20):

This one uses a regular expression and returns null if the parameter doesn't exist or doesn't have any value:

```
function getQuery(q) {
   return (window.location.search.match(new RegExp('[?&]' + q + '=([^&]+)')) || [, null])[1];
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks this is what i needed :)

Comment: Gets the job done perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect code, Thank you!

Comment: Worked perfectly and very tiny code part. Thanks.

Comment: wow, nice one..

Answer (score 13):

I do it like this (to retrieve a specific get-parameter, here 'parameterName'):

```
var parameterValue = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.match(/(\?|&)parameterName\=([^&]*)/)[2]);
```

Comment: This is nice and short. I also prefer to do that in my code.

Comment: This is nice and works, but generates an error when the parameter is omitted...  You can fix it by storing the match in a variable and checking if it equals `null`, but that ruins the one-line nature :/

Answer (score 9):

Here I've made this code to transform the GET parameters into an object to use them more easily.

```
// Get Nav URL
function getNavUrl() {
    // Get URL
    return window.location.search.replace("?", "");
};

function getParameters(url) {
    // Params obj
    var params = {};
    // To lowercase
    url = url.toLowerCase();
    // To array
    url = url.split('&');

    // Iterate over URL parameters array
    var length = url.length;
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
        // Create prop
        var prop = url[i].slice(0, url[i].search('='));
        // Create Val
        var value = url[i].slice(url[i].search('=')).replace('=', '');
        // Params New Attr
        params[prop] = value;
    }
    return params;
};

// Call of getParameters
console.log(getParameters(getNavUrl()));
```

Answer (score 6):

To get the parameters as a JSON object:

```
console.log(getUrlParameters())

function getUrlParameters() {
    var out = {};
    var str = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
    var subs = str.split(`&`).map((si)=>{var keyVal = si.split(`=`); out[keyVal[0]]=keyVal[1];});
    return out
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that `object.toSource()` only works on Firefox. Replace the first line with `alert(JSON.stringify(getUrlParameters()))`

Answer (score 4):

I have created a simple JavaScript function to access GET parameters from URL.

Just include this JavaScript source and you can access `get` parameters.
E.g.: in http://example.com/index.php?language=french, the `language` variable can be accessed as `$_GET["language"]`. Similarly, a list of all parameters will be stored in a variable `$_GET_Params` as an array.  Both the JavaScript and HTML are provided in the following code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- This script is required -->
    <script>
    function $_GET() {
      // Get the Full href of the page e.g. http://www.google.com/files/script.php?v=1.8.7&country=india
      var href = window.location.href;

      // Get the protocol e.g. http
      var protocol = window.location.protocol + "//";

      // Get the host name e.g. www.google.com
      var hostname = window.location.hostname;

      // Get the pathname e.g. /files/script.php
      var pathname = window.location.pathname;

      // Remove protocol part
      var queries = href.replace(protocol, '');

      // Remove host part
      queries = queries.replace(hostname, '');

      // Remove pathname part
      queries = queries.replace(pathname, '');

      // Presently, what is left in the variable queries is : ?v=1.8.7&country=india

      // Perform query functions if present
      if (queries != "" && queries != "?") {

    // Remove question mark '?'
        queries = queries.slice(1);

        // Split all the different queries
        queries = queries.split("&");

        // Get the number of queries
        var length = queries.length;

        // Declare global variables to store keys and elements
        $_GET_Params = new Array();
        $_GET = {};

        // Perform functions per query
        for (var i  = 0; i < length; i++) {

          // Get the present query
          var key = queries[i];

          // Split the query and the value
          key = key.split("=");

          // Assign value to the $_GET variable
          $_GET[key[0]] = [key[1]];

          // Assign value to the $_GET_Params variable
          $_GET_Params[i] = key[0];
        }
      }
    }

    // Execute the function
    $_GET();
    </script>
    <h1>GET Parameters</h1>
    <h2>Try to insert some get parameter and access it through JavaScript</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var getQueryParam = function(param) {
    var found;
    window.location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {
        if (param ==  item.split("=")[0]) {
            found = item.split("=")[1];
        }
    });
    return found;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example based on Kat's and [Bakudan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript/5448595#5448595) examples, but making it a just a bit more generic.

```
function getParams ()
{
    var result = {};
    var tmp = [];

    location.search
        .substr (1)
        .split ("&")
        .forEach (function (item)
        {
            tmp = item.split ("=");
            result [tmp[0]] = decodeURIComponent (tmp[1]);
        });

    return result;
}

location.getParams = getParams;

console.log (location.getParams());
console.log (location.getParams()["returnurl"]);
```

Comment: There isn't an answer or comment by the user name "Kat". User names can change at any time. What does it refer to?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a library instead of rolling your own implementation, check out https://github.com/jgallen23/querystring.

Answer (score 2):

This solution handles URL decoding:

```
var params = function() {
    function urldecode(str) {
        return decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
    }

    function transformToAssocArray( prmstr ) {
        var params = {};
        var prmarr = prmstr.split("&");
        for ( var i = 0; i < prmarr.length; i++) {
            var tmparr = prmarr[i].split("=");
            params[tmparr[0]] = urldecode(tmparr[1]);
        }
        return params;
    }

    var prmstr = window.location.search.substr(1);
    return prmstr != null && prmstr != "" ? transformToAssocArray(prmstr) : {};
}();
```

Usage:

```
console.log('someParam GET value is', params['someParam']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *search* function available in the *location* object. The search function gives the parameter part of the URL. Details can be found in *[Location Object](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/location.shtml)*.

You will have to parse the resulting string for getting the variables and their values, e.g. splitting them on '='.

Answer (score 1):

My solution expands on @tak3r's.

It returns an empty object when there are no query parameters and supports the array notation `?a=1&a=2&a=3`:

```
function getQueryParams () {
  function identity (e) { return e; }
  function toKeyValue (params, param) {
    var keyValue = param.split('=');
    var key = keyValue[0], value = keyValue[1];

    params[key] = params[key]?[value].concat(params[key]):value;
    return params;
  }
  return decodeURIComponent(window.location.search).
    replace(/^\?/, '').split('&').
    filter(identity).
    reduce(toKeyValue, {});
}
```

Comment: There isn't currently any answer or comment with user name "tak3r" (user names can change at any time). What does it refer to?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using AngularJS, you can use `$routeParams` using `ngRoute` module

You have to add a module to your app

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
```

Now you can use service `$routeParams`:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($routeParams) {
  console.log($routeParams); // JSON object
}
```