# IE/JS: reduce on an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, reduce

my javascript Application works on firefox and chrome very well. But it seams to be broken on Internet Explorer (IE 8).

I did not get an error Message on the console-log. By debugging the code I notice, that the application breaks on the following line:

```
 series.reduce(visit, []);
```

The whole function exits at this point.
I know, that `reduce` works for arrays, but `console.info(typeof(series))` tells: object

But this object exactly looks like an array - and it works on FF/Chrome.
Could this be the reason, why IE stops processing the function at this point?
And: how to handle this at IE?

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Reduce is not supported until IE 9 : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/reduce#Browser_compatibility

That link does have a workaround bit of code for browsers that don't support reduce.

Comment: oh jeah... thats it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can also find other ES5 JavaScript array functions polyfills here:

http://tech.pro/tutorial/1834/working-with-es5-javascript-array-functions-in-modern-and-legacy-browsers#indexof