# spring security 3 authentication-failure-url change

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm developing web application on spring where authentication is made with Spring Security 3 and LDAP.

This is a form-login snippet from my code:

```
<security:form-login
    authentication-failure-url="/index.xhtml?error=true"
    default-target-url="/SomeDefaultUrl.xhtml"
    login-page="/index.xhtml" />
```

When authentication fails my application is redirected to "/index.xhtml?error=true" url. The problem is that I don't know how to catch "error" variable and show some authentication failure message in index.xhtml file. I'm not using Spring mvc.

The second problem is that changing of authentication-failure-url doesn't work.

```
<security:form-login
    authentication-failure-url="/error.xhtml"
    default-target-url="/SomeDefaultUrl.xhtml"
    login-page="/index.xhtml" />
```

I changed authentication-failure-url, but despite of this change, it still redirects to index.xhtml file without any variables.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important: `/index.xhtml?error=true` sends `error` as `GET` parameter.

If your `index.xhtml` is a JSP file you can access that param using implicit `request` reference:

```
<%= request.getParameter("error") %>
```

If `index.xhtml` is URL of your web controller method/servlet you need to get `error` param from `Request` object.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException 
{       
    String error = req.getParameter("error");
}
```

Finally, if your `index.xhtml` is a plain html file, you can use Java Script to get that parameter:
[How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

For your second question: make sure you properly rebuild your project. It looks like it didn't notice your changes.

Comment: Thank you for you great advises. 
About second question: I rebuild project and it noticed my change, because it redirected to `index.xhtml` file and not to `index.xhtml?error=true`
I think when value of authentication-failure-url parameter is not _acceptable_  it automatically redirects to index.xhtml. But I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 3):

If your `index.xhtml` is a JSP, you can do this (directly from Spring 3 Recipes book):

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
    Login error.
    Reason ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<security:form-login
    authentication-failure-url="/error.xhtml"
    default-target-url="/SomeDefaultUrl.xhtml"
    login-page="/index.xhtml" />
```

"I changed authentication-failure-url, but despite of this change, it still redirects to index.xhtml file without any variables."

**Answer:** Please define the below intercept-url inside your `<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"></http>` body.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/error.xhtml" access="permitAll"/>
```

You may not have defined access to */error.xhtml* and that is why *authentication-failure-url* value is not acceptable and is falling through to the next logical url defined i.e. */index.html*

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions here worked for me, then I found this question, which had the correct solution for me:
[spring security 3.1. custom authentication-failure-url with url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199423/spring-security-3-1-custom-authentication-failure-url-with-url-parameters)