# spring security 3.1. custom authentication-failure-url with url parameters

Tags: java, spring-security

I googled and tried lot of variants for some hours but without any success.
Please help me to find a solution.

Spring version: Spring 3.1

I have login page. Login page depends on URL parameter:

```
/login?code=client1
```

or

```
/login?code=client2
```

So client1 and client2 has different login pages.

security.xml:

```
<sec:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/start" authentication-failure-url="/login"/>
```

So if user make wrong authentication I show him /login page...
But point is I have to show login page with corresponding code parameter.

What should I do? Have tyou examples please?

Thanks a lot for advance.

**UPDATE #1:**

I created FailureHandler class:

```
public class GRSAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) {

}

}
```

What should I write inside to get redirect to needed URL?
Please if you can give me more details.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [`SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.html) and implement a different [`RedirectStrategy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/RedirectStrategy.html) which redirect to the configured URL and adds the original query string to the redirected URL.

```
public class QueryStringPropagateRedirectStrategy extends DefaultRedirectStrategy {

    public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, String url) throws IOException {
        String urlWithOriginalQueryString = url + "?" + request.getQueryString();
        super.sendRedirect(request, response, urlWithOriginalQueryString );
    }

}
```

Authentication failure handler configurations

```
<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="redirectStrategy" ref="queryStringPropagateRedirectStrategy" />
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login" />
</bean>

<bean id="queryStringPropagateRedirectStrategy" class="...QueryStringPropagateRedirectStrategy" />
```

Comment: See, thanks. And last stupid question: how should I link the strategy to my handler?

Comment: Does easy way to get an auth exception exist? I have different exceptions and different corresponding info to show to user. Should I create my handler and override saveException() method? Thanks again.

Comment: not working on spring-security 4.0.3, request.getQueryString() is always null