# Spring Security custom authentication failure handler redirect with parameter

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a problem with Spring Security authentication failure handler redirect with parameter.

In security config when I use

```java
failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
```

it works. But when I use custom authentication failure handler (as shown below), it always returns: `url/login.html`

```java
getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/login.html?error=true");
```

or

```java
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.html?error=true");
```

I don't know whats wrong. Why does it not show the parameter `?error=true`?

Info: I am using Spring + JSF + Hibernate + Spring Security

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html")
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)// .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")//.successHandler(authSuccsessHandler)
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access.html")
            .and()
        .headers()
            .defaultsDisabled()
            .frameOptions()
            .sameOrigin()
            .cacheControl();

    http
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

This is custom authentication failure handler:

```java
@Component
public class CustomAuthFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/login.html?error=true");

    }
}
```

I will change parameter for some cases.

Comment: This answer might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199423/spring-security-3-1-custom-authentication-failure-url-with-url-parameters

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You didn't allow anonymous access to URL `/login.html?error=true`, so you are redirected to the login page (`/login.html`).

[`AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer#permitAll`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.html#permitAll--) allows access (for anyone) to failure URL but not for custom failure handler:

> Ensures the urls for `failureUrl(String)` as well as for the `HttpSecurityBuilder`, the `getLoginPage()` and `getLoginProcessingUrl()` are granted access to any user.

You have to allow access explicitly with [`AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry#antMatchers`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#antMatchers-java.lang.String...-):

> Maps a List of `AntPathRequestMatcher` instances that do not care which `HttpMethod` is used.

and [`ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl#permitAll`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html#permitAll--):

> Specify that URLs are allowed by anyone.

You don't have to allow the exact URL `/login.html?error=true`, because [`AntPathRequestMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html) ignores the [query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) string:

> Matcher which compares a pre-defined ant-style pattern against the URL ( `servletPath` + `pathInfo`) of an `HttpServletRequest`. The query string of the URL is ignored and matching is case-insensitive or case-sensitive depending on the arguments passed into the constructor.

Your modified configuration:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login.html").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html")
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)// .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")//.successHandler(authSuccsessHandler)
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access.html")
            .and()
        .headers()
            .defaultsDisabled()
            .frameOptions()
            .sameOrigin()
            .cacheControl();

    http
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: May I ask what is the advantage of calling getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/login.html?error=true")  over response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.html?error=true")

Comment: @AndreyM.Stepanov It is just a way to support different strategies. The default is [DefaultRedirectStrategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.11.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/DefaultRedirectStrategy.html) It calculates the right URL.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of OAuth token failure, I am getting below response, which is inconsistent with app response style.

```
    {
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Invalid access token: 4cbc6f1c-4d47-44bd-89bc-92a8c86d88dbsdfsdfs"
}
```

I just wanted to use common response object for the consistency.
Following approach worked for me.
Build your resource server with your custom entry-point object

```
@Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomOAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint());
  }
```

and here is your custom entry point

```
 public class CustomOAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint extends OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint{

  public CustomOAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
    super.setExceptionTranslator(new CustomOAuth2WebResponseExceptionTranslator());
  }
}
```

here is your custom WebResponseExceptionTranslator, In my case I have just used a replica of DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator and rewritten handleOAuth2Exception method.

```
CustomOAuth2WebResponseExceptionTranslator implements WebResponseExceptionTranslator<Response> {
....
.....
 private ResponseEntity<Response> handleOAuth2Exception(OAuth2Exception e) throws IOException {

        int status = e.getHttpErrorCode();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        headers.set("Pragma", "no-cache");
        if (status == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value() || (e instanceof InsufficientScopeException)) {
            headers.set("WWW-Authenticate", String.format("%s %s", OAuth2AccessToken.BEARER_TYPE, e.getSummary()));
        }

        ResponseEntity<Response> response =new ResponseEntity<>(new Response().message(e.getMessage()).status(StatusEnum.ERROR)
            .errorType(e.getClass().getName()), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        return response;

    }
```

Result looks like

```
    {
    "status": "error",
    "message": "Invalid access token: 4cbc6f1c-4d47-44bd-89bc-92a8c86d88dbsdfsdfs",
    "error_type": "org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidTokenException"
}
```