# spring security custom authentication failure handler not forwarding

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a custom Authentication failure handler as below

```
@Component
public class MyAuthFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler{
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(exception instanceof AccountExpiredException && username != null){
            // do some internal lookup and set values in request and redirect
            System.out.println("Forwarding.... " );
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/recoverAccount").forward(request, response);
        }
    }

}
```

And configured handler in security config as below

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.csrf().disable()
              .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/reset","/resetStatus","/recoverAccount","/login**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
              .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .successHandler(successHandler)
                    .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
              .logout()
                    .permitAll();
```

And on login when ever `AccountExpiredException` is thrown the handler is invoked and I am getting `Forwarding` printed out, but forward is not working and redirected to login page without any error. Redirect is also not working.

I checked the document, but there is no information about forwards. 
I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43844188/2151491) post and verified that `/recoverAccount` is allowed for unauthorized access.

By testing repeatedly I can see `/recoverAccount` is blocked and redirected to default login page, but not able to find what cause this. Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a silly mistake, I misspelled /recovrAccount in MyAuthFailureHandler. 
Anyhow for those looking to implement forward authentication failure handler below are the steps,

1. Implement AuthenticationFailureHandler or extend SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler
2. Override onAuthenticationFailure method and write your own logic and forwardto controller/url using request
3. Configure your failure authentication implemented above as failureHandler in Security config
4. Don't forget to allow access to forward controller/url in security config using antmatchers.