# the added class is not being remembered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigation with 2 buttons, when clicking a button it loads a new page (new page load), when clicking the button, a class with classname selected should be added...
It does that partially - It add's the class, but when it loads the new page, the class is removed again? How do I make the class stick to what the user has clicked?

```
$(document).on("click", ".list-mode button", function () {
    $(".list-mode button").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: You can't. Javascript does not persist state. You will need some form of storing which value was selected across HTTP requests (cookies, database, local storage...)

Comment: You'll have to remember the class on the server, and write it back while displaying the next page

Comment: Ok, thx for the answer - I solved it by using LocalStorage to save the users click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're navigating to a new page, changes you've made using JavaScript to the current page aren't going to appear in the new one. You really have three options:

1. Add the correct class to the correct element in the HTML of the new page using server-side code.
2. Add the correct class to the correct element using JavaScript in the new page; you'll need a way to determine which element the class should be added to (possibly part of the URL of the new page).
3. Use AJAX navigation, and rather than loading a completely new page simply load the new content and replace part of the already loaded page.

Comment: There's the cookie option as well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sure, cookies could be part of the implementation of either option 1 or 2. I don't think there a separate option all of their own though; you still have to *use* the cookie.

Comment: Option 2 here would be my preference. This answer may help with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need cookies or DOM storage for this.

Whenever the page is going to be abandoned, you need to store somewhere what the user did last time and initialize the whole buttons with the stored settings.

As you're using jQuery, handle the `document.ready` event and initialize there the buttons whenever the page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Initialize the whole buttons
});
```

Comment: *"You need cookies or DOM storage for this."* Not necessarily, as Anthony pointed out, you could send the information to the server and persist it there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I prefer to store this in the browser rather than in some _server session state_. We don't know the actual underlying requirements. I mean: maybe this "tracking" can dead whenever the user leaves the website so why using the server memory for something like this?

Comment: @ Matías: Right. But "need" is a very strong word, it excludes other possibilities.

Comment: @NickyChristensen Well, when I gave you the hint of _DOM storage_ I was talking about _local storage_. I'm glad you got the right solution!

Comment: @NickyChristensen Now I see you checked another answer as the right one. While it's up to you to choose what you liked more, I believe that, if you solved your problem using _local storage_, this is exactly what I pointed out in my answer.