# Change content according to URL

Tags: php, javascript, html, url

I want to be able to change a specific value of html of my page based on the url of my website. For example, If I want to change the value to 'example' I'd go to mysite.com/page.php?value=example

Is it possible for me to do this without having to set each value in a php include script?

Comment: If you want to get the value from javascript you can use [this][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your `php` page, change this:

```
<p>This is sample text and the word example.</p>
```

to this:

```
<p>This is sample text and the word <?php echo $_GET['value']; ?></p>
```

This will print whatever value comes after `?value=` in your URL onto the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply something like this in your jQuery code to check the page name within a given URL, and then change the value of a specific section on that page!  No need for PHP, this is all front-end logic.

```
var urlspot = document.URL.split('/');
if((urlspot[3] == 'pagename')) { 
  $('#content').text('now i want to change my text on this page');
}
```

And just change the urlspot[x] to the appropriate number based on location in your URL. It doesn't have to be 3. It could be 1, 2, 3, ,4, etc...You have have to play with it.