# How to work with the URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For example I have the URL:
http://www.website.com/example?something=abc&a=b

How can I get the something's content, "abc" and the content of a as strings?

Thanks in advance,
Mateiaru

Comment: document.URL or window.location You can get current url as string.You can manipulate it.Did you try anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

Comment: http://snipplr.com/view/19838/ - Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//var url = window.location.href;
var url = "http://www.website.com/example?something=abc&a=b";
var attributes = url.split("?")[1].split("&");
var keyValue = {};
for(i in attributes)
{
    var pair = attributes[i].split("=");
    keyValue[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}

alert(keyValue["something"]);
alert(keyValue["a"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var path = window.location.href;
var index = path.indexOf('?');
var paramstr = path.substring(index + 1);
var paramstrs = paramstr.split('&');
paramstrs.forEach(function(str, index){
    var parts = str.split('=');
    alert('value of ' + parts[0] + ' is ' + parts[1])
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function helper:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}
```

Then call it like:

```
var aValue = getURLParameter(a);
```