# Call javascript function straight from url address bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video-streaming

firstly I should write that I am not good in javascript at all :). What I need to do. Lets say I have some webpage, for example http://mediathek.rbb-online.de/rbb-fernsehen/heimatjournal/ulli-zelle-ist-in-brandenburg-unterwegs-ein-ausflug-nach?documentId=15725820

There is video in this page and I want to get straight link to this video and play it from straight typing to url address bar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <![CDATA[
                  something...
                  something...

                function initPlayer(){
                    jQuery("#player-15725820").empty();

                    something...

                  mediaCollection.addMedia(0);
                  mediaCollection.addMediaStream(0, 1,
                  "rtmp://ondemand.rbb-online.de/ondemand/",
                  "mp4:rbb/heimatjournal/sendung/heimatjournal_20130706_sdg_m_16_9_512x288.mp4", "akamai");
                  mediaCollection.addMedia(1);
                  mediaCollection.addMediaStream(1, 1, "", "http://http-stream.rbb-online.de/rbb/heimatjournal/sendung/heimatjournal_20130706_sdg_m_16_9_512x288.mp4", "akamai");
```

Is there any way to setup video

"mp4:rbb/heimatjournal/sendung/heimatjournal_20130706_sdg_m_16_9_512x288.mp4

straightly from url like stream??

Comment: You can find more info about running javascript from adress bar by searching `javascript bookmarlket` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet , though this question seems to be about something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to understand what you're asking for here, perhaps when on the page you want to run a function such as?

```
function getMP4Strings(s) {
    var i = -1, j, k, a = [];
    while (-1 !== (i = s.indexOf('mp4', i + 1))) { // for each "mp4"
        j = s.lastIndexOf('"', i) + 1;             // get previous "
        k = s.indexOf('"', i);                     // get next "
        a.push(s.slice(j, k));                     // store string between them
    }
    return a;
}
getMP4Strings(document.body.innerHTML);
/* [
    "mp4:rbb/heimatjournal/sendung/heimatjournal_20130706_sdg_m_16_9_512x288.mp4",
    "mp4:rbb/heimatjournal/sendung/heimatjournal_20130706_sdg_m_16_9_512x288.mp4", 
    "http://http-stream.rbb-online.de/rbb/heimatjournal/sendung/heimatjournal_20130706_sdg_m_16_9_512x288.mp4"
] */
```

Comment: There is a problem that I am writing a video crawler. I am able to get this information

Comment: <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flashContentplayer-15725820" name="flashContentplayer-15725820" align="middle" data="/rbb/static/player/base/flash/PluginFlash.swf" width="1" ...">
  <param name="flashvars" value="id=player-15725820&amp;baseUrl=/rbb/static/player/&amp;configPath=/rbb/static/player/base/flash/conf/config.xml&amp;skinPath=/rbb/static/player/base/flash/css/finalSkin.css&amp;uniqueId=A19A7729-2293-4806-AABE-D486FC0CD03F&amp;version=3.3.0&amp;cdns=akamai&amp;.."/>
</object>

Comment: And I am asking if it is possible to use some information from this output and get url of video (.mp4) and play it...

Comment: In my question there is some Javascript stuff (as I have written.. I dont now anything about javascript)... and I am interested if it is possible to play video in some way.. maybe from this javascript stuff

Comment: @JohnnyGreenwood from the code you posted I cannot see how even the player itself knows how to transform the ID into a url :) Open your console on the network tab, go to a cut down test page, take note of each request made, specifically for things including the ID number, find out where the id-to-url transformation is actually done, you may be required to fetch data.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.search` contains the querystring as a string.  You could [split this into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript) and retrieve the `documentId` value.

1. `window.location.search` // ?documentId=3243242
2. Retrieve the documentId value, many ways to do this have been [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript) before on stackoverflow
3. Now you can access the value, something like `paramsObj // {documentId: 3243242}`

`"mp4:rbb/heimatjournal/sendung/heimatjournal_" + paramObj['documentId'] + "_sdg_m_16_9_512x288.mp4"`

Then you could use that value to load the corresponding video

Comment: @JohnnyGreenwood are you trying to pull `documentId=15725820` and use the value of `documentId` to load `mp4:rbb/heimatjournal/sendung/heimatjournal_{{ documentIdValueHere}}_sdg_m_16_9_512x288.mp4`??

Comment: @JohnnyGreenwood but `'20130706' !== documentId`

Comment: This is true and great answer but I am afraid that my question is obviously wrong question and actually I'm not even sure if it is possible to do in javascript... I am writing a video crawler. I am able to get this information:

Comment: <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flashContentplayer-15725820" name="flashContentplayer-15725820" align="middle" data="/rbb/static/player/base/flash/PluginFlash.swf" width="1" ..."> <param name="flashvars" value="id=player-15725820&amp;baseUrl=/rbb/static/player/&amp;configPath=/rbb/st‌​atic/player/base/flash/conf/config.xml&amp;skinPath=/rbb/static/player/base/flash‌​/css/finalSkin.css&amp;uniqueId=A19A7729-2293-4806-AABE-D486FC0CD03F&amp;version=‌​3.3.0&amp;cdns=akamai&amp;.."/> </object>

Comment: And I am asking if it is possible to use some information from this output and get url of video (.mp4) and play it...