# Stripping URL Argument

Tags: javascript, url

An example URL that opens my page:
https://mydomain.com/stuff/mypage.php?id=aslkj34rf340if0i3m4flakmf

Is there anyway with javascript to strip everything after .php so that when the user bookmarks the page the bookmark just has https://mydomain.com/stuff/mypage.php as the link?

Comment: set it as `window.location =  https://mydomain.com/stuff/mypage.php` only then.

Comment: is the id loading specific content? Or just a referring id?

Answer (score 0):

you need to take a look at this one [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

just use the `window.location.search`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by:

```
var url = document.URL;
var urlparts= url.split('?');
//here is the link you want
var bookmark = urlparts[0];
```