# set url value globaly in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to calculate bonus. On the first page two options: yes and no.

If I select yes, piccal.html?value=yes

```
<a onClick="window.location.replace('piccal.html?value=yes')">
```

When I select no, piccal.html?value=no

```
<a onClick="window.location.replace('piccal.html?value=no')">
```

If I have yes then calculate to bonus otherwise not

On calculator page there are 3 links to other pages.

```
<a href="piccal.html" class="btn noselect"></a>         
<a href="picinfo.html" class="btn noselect">PIC Grant Information</a>
<a href="#">Contact Us</a>
```

piccal.html is a calculator page if i will select this link from inside then i have no value  "yes" or "no" . how to set url yes or no value as default for all page if any value selected from another page

I think you are getting my question.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @PratikJoshi - user might not be able to express his question, but that does not mean he is a KID.

Comment: @Ashish Just flag comments that are rude and let the mods delete them.  Better than filling the pages with arguments :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `onclick`, instead of `href`?

Comment: bacause i have not to go on first page for selecting value i have to make selected value globaly if first time select yes then all page have yes oterwise not

Comment: this is a mobile application window.location.replace prevent from goback

Comment: Looking at your edit that shows links using the href attribute, my code below should work, but it would need to be executed after those links are on the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking what I think, then you want to persist the querystring from page to page.  This can be simple or very involved, depending on many other factors, but this is a simple answer that will work if none of your links have querystrings in them.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    if (location.search !== "") {
        $("a").each(function() {
            this.href += location.search
        });
    }
});
```

Put that code in a js file and include it in every page that you need to persist the querystring.  It will add the querystring to the href value of every link on the page.  Is it perfect?  Absolutely not, but it will resolve this particular scenario you describe.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function setUrl(newUrl, force) {
    if (url === newUrl && !force) {
         return;
     }
     url = newUrl;
     $iframe.attr('src', newUrl + '?_app_platform=' + os);
     $url.each(function () {
         if ($(this).data('url') === newUrl) {
             $(this).addClass('active');
         } else {
             $(this).removeClass('active');
         }
     });
 }
```