# Pass GET variable to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, query-string

I'm using GET to retrieve a query string from my url e.g:

```
index.php?page=quiz
```

Then I want to run my function `getPage` which is JS using the value of `page=` (in this case it's `quiz`)

So I have an onload function which only runs if `page` has a value:

```
<body
    <?php
        if(!empty($_GET["page"])){
            //echo "onload='runPage(" . $_GET["page"] . ")'";
            echo "onload='runPage()'";
        }
    ?>
>
```

This basically works out as:

```
<body onload="runPage(quiz)">
```

I want to pass `quiz` in this case to the `runPage` function so that I can use it within it. For example:

```
function runPage(this){
  var page = this;
  console.log("Page = " + page);
}
```

But this just throws an error saying `quiz` is undefined... where is my logic wrong?

Edit: So I've updated my code and am now getting:

```
<body onload='runPage("quiz")'>
```

But now I want to take "quiz" and pass it to this function:

```
function runPage(){
// run stuff in here using the value of that variable e.g:
console.log("You've come through from the URL with quiz on the end");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Comment: you'll find your GET Variable in window.location.search as well

Comment: quiz is an undefined var, you should pass it as a string:

`<body onload="runPage('quiz')">`

Comment: You need to transform quiz to string otherwise it would try to evaluate a variable called "quiz" which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the variable in there. For an inline event handler, it's a little trickier:

```
<body <?php
  if( !empty($_GET['page'])) {
    echo 'onLoad="runPage('.htmlspecialchars(json_encode($_GET['page'])).');"';
  }
?> >
```

Normally, you can just use `json_encode` to pass a variable from PHP to JavaScript in a safe, XSS-proof manner. But because you are in an inline event handler, you need to also use `htmlspecialchars` to ensure that it doesn't break your HTML context (as that could potentially be another XSS vector otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your string in quotes. Because you're already nesting quotes in your PHP code you'll need to escape them like this:

```
echo "onload='runPage(\"" . $_GET["page"] . "\")'";
```

Be careful, though. This is susceptible to script injection. At the very least you need to sanitise the contents of `$_GET['page']`.

Your Javascript function then becomes:

```
function runPage(page){
  console.log("Page = " + page);
}
```

Note that `this` is a keyword and has a special meaning in Javascript. You don't need it anyway - just use a different variable name.

Comment: What happen if I set up you the bomb, and send you to `http://example.com/index.php?page="); alert("All your base are belong to us` ?

Comment: OK so I tried this. But I don't understand how to get that value: ("thisvaluehere") from the onload and be able to use it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

`location.search`   Return the query portion of a Url

URL:index.php?page=quiz

location.search="?page=quiz"

Comment: Not quite what's being asked here... Admittedly the question is awkwardly worded, but you should pay attention ^_^

Answer (score -2):

```
function runPage(){
  var page = '<?php echo $_GET['page']?>';
  if(page!=''){
    console.log("Page = " + page);
  }      
}
```

Comment: Please explain the code you have posted - don't just post a block of code!

Comment: I left it for you to do

Comment: Its better to edit the answer as you like rather downvote.