# Get URL parameters with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have the following tag inside my HTML:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://XX/teste1.php?BLABLABLA"></script>`

Is there somewhay inside teste1.php, using JS to retrieve the parameters BLABLABLA? If I use window.location.href I get the index.php location (of course) but I need to get the parameters sent to the external resource using JS and not PHP.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @amandanovaes . Please see my answer, I think that is what you're after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understood what you are after. Take a look the following fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/gK58u/2/

You can see I'm manually loading in jQuery, and then getting the `src` from the script declaration.

===================

**HTML** Add an `id` to your script declaration

`<script id="jquerysrc" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js?key=test"></script>`

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scriptsource = "";
    scriptsource = $("#jquerysrc").attr("src");
    alert(scriptsource);
});
```

This will allow you see the url that your external js file is coming from. This is more a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, without using jQuery.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),i,src;

for(i=0;i<scripts.length;i++){
   src = scripts[i].src;
   if (src && src.indexOf('?')>=0){
       console.log(src.substring(src.indexOf('?')+1));
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem you don't understand how PHP and JS works together.
Php generate HTML (maybe JS and CSS too). Then when this html is loaded by a client, JS is executed.

To get it in PHP or JS, you can use regex or modify the url from `?BLABLABLA` to `?key=BLABLABLA`. In PHP, "BLABLABLA" will be stored in $_GET['key']

---

**EDIT :**

well I misunderstood your question.

From "[How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)" :

## -------------------------

With the `window.location` object. This code gives you GET without the question mark.

```
window.location.search.replace( "?", "" );
```

## -------------------------

From your example it will return `BLABLABLA`

[window.location DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

---

**EDIT2 :**

When you generate your Javascript in teste.php, you should do this :

```
$str = "";
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $str = $key;
}
echo "var getParam = ".$str.";";
```

I don't see how to avoid foreach if you don't know what is given. You may have to rebuilt the parameters string ("?xxx=sss&ddd=zz...")

Now you JS variable getParam should contains BLABLABLA

Apolo

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, and actually isn't true: there is nothing stopping you from getting the query string via js...

Comment: I know very well PHP but I need to do that with JS. With JS it's easy to retrieve GET parameters using x = window.location.href and then I can parse the parameters. It's very easy.

Comment: I updated my post, should solve your problem =) (no downvote please... =D)

Comment: but it still does not answer my question. I need to get the parameters sent to the external script. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Ok I have another Idea, I'm updating.

Comment: Feel free to tell me if it solved your problem or not.

Comment: @Apolo I thank you your effort but it still does not answer my question. The call is made to an external resource and whenever I use window.location it will give me back the page itself not the script url call.

Comment: You are coding teste1.php ? Not sure I understand. Because my second edit is no more about using window.location =)

Comment: You are right but your code uses PHP and I cannot use PHP in this particular case. @mituw16 presented a really nice answer. It's a creative one but works fine in my case! Thank you anyway for trying help me!

Answer (score 0):

Currently JavaScript don't have any of the built-in function for such purpose. What you're talking about i.e. **BLABLABLA** is known as **Query String**. Which is attacked to the URL to make a dynamic web page (change the content depending on the condition)

#### First Method

Is to get the whole URL, and then replacing the URL with empty string and so on to get only the last element.

#### Second method

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1762944) was posted with a function (custom function, not a builtIn function). In which you pass on a parameter to the method, which gets the parameter values for you. It is easy to understand too.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

To call the function, you use `getParameterByName('prodId')`. Use it inside a function or variable and you're good to go.

Comment: using location.search will retrieve the parameters of the page itself not the parameters sent to the script external call.

Comment: I actually AM talking about the page parameters. That was a function to get all of the functions and then search for the function passed on.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but it's not what I need. Thank you anyway.