# Popup message with location.replace

Tags: jquery, ajax, window

I am trying to redirect the user to a certain page upon registeration using the following line:

```
window.location.replace(value2);
```

where value2 is the URL. I would like to attach some message that appears as a popup window with it.
Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: just try adding `alert()` before it

Comment: the alert appears before redirection. I need it to appear after it in the next page.

Comment: just pass one dummy parameter in url and in next page check for url parameter and display message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
var value2 = "samp2.php?success=Yes";
window.location.replace(value2);
```

in samp2.php

write this in first line

```
if(isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == "Yes")
{
    print '<script type="text/javascript">';
    print 'window.onload = function(e){';
    print 'alert("Welcome to page 2")';
    print '};';
    print '</script>';
}
//header("refresh:1,url=samp.php"); // this is optional
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a GET parameter to the URL on redirection

```
var url= actualURL+'?message=1';
window.location.replace(url);
```

You can find how to retrieve get parameter from URL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

On the receiving page you can check the value of `message` parameter and display appropriate message from JavaScript.

By this way you can do it without server-side code change.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript Confirm for this:

```
var r = confirm("Do you want to be redirected?!");
if (r == true) {
    window.location.replace(value2);
} else {
    alert( 'Okay then, We will stay right here' );
}
```

Comment: The scenario is as follows:
button pressed on page 1 -> redirection->landing page 2 with message "Welcome to page 2"

The above example will just alert on the same page with is not needed.

Comment: Well, then you need to do as krishna said. A javascript on one site, cant pass along a javascript to any other site. Have your value2 param as for example: value2 = "http://www.yourdomain.com/?message=This message will be shown"; then on site 2, make a javascript that checks if the get parameter message is set, and if yes, fire an alert with its content.