# Input value in URL

Tags: javascript, url

I have a site where I enter an input it brings up a page specific to my input;

The URL is something like this; https://hum.drum.something.com/cgi-bin/nhc.pl

What I'd like to do is send out links like this
https://hum.drum.something.com/cgi-bin/nhc.pl?MAN_search=4AA11 with 4AA11 being the value or id="myName" I would enter on the site.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Look into PHP get variables.

Comment: @SpencerMay, You can't say, "Look into PHP..." when we don't even know what tech the OP is using...  (It looks like perl, by the way.)

Comment: I think this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Make a similar form:

```
<form action="nhc.pl" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="MAN_search" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

This will submit the appropriate GET request to your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.URL` to get the current URL and examine the last X characters as you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that is asked many times, and could also be answered by searching Google for two minutes.

However, I'll try to give you a short answer.
Getting variables from the URL is much easier using php. All you need to do to access the value of the variable is:

```
$_GET["MAN_Search"]
```

If you want to achieve the same using only JavaScript, the solution would look something like this:

```
    function getQueryVariable(variable) {
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
   }
```

If you would call getQueryVariable("MAN_Search"), the result would be 4AA11 (taking your example URL).