# javascript split URL Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i am new in javascript before i read the case split using the function. I just followed but not understand it. Can you guys give me a link or guide to explain how it work? tks a ton

```
var first = getUrlVars()["id"];
var second = getUrlVars()["page"];

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question is

Comment: What do you want to know? [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is a different function then you use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Comment: Yes i do know hot split works (from java) but how 'this case' it worked. For last time i basically followed the link and it worked.

Comment: Can you give a URL example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function return the value of each varrian from url.

In your code, you want to get id, page from url. I guest you have a url like : your-page?**id**=value&**page**=value, and you want to get them, don't you?

You need to read the replace function at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: tks men! Got that. But what is the "[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]" mean??

Comment: Hehe, read http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_symbols.asp and some related HTML Charsets

Answer (score 0):

There is a kind of function you would like. Hope you will understand this :

```
var getUrlVars = function( url ){
    if( !url.match( /\?/ ) ) return {};
    var paramsfull = url.replace( /^.*\?/, "" ).split( /\&/g );
    var params = {};
    var _temp;
    for( var p in paramsfull ){
        _temp = paramsfull[ p ].split( /\=/ );
        params[ _temp[ 0 ] ] = _temp[ 1 ];
    }
    return params;
}

var first = getUrlVars( window.location.href )[ "id" ];
var second = getUrlVars( window.location.href )[ "page" ];
```