# Clone selected dropdown value after page redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning jquery... This is my problem, I need to clone the value selected from web page 1 and redirect webpage1 to webpage2...

I found some codes here and tried to combine them...but the code below only redirects and does not clone dropdown value to webpage2 based on the selected value from webpage1....

```
function moveTo(optionValue) {
    if(optionValue=="") return false;
        window.location='.htm'+optionValue;
    } 
    var $orginalDiv = $('#container');
    var $clonedDiv = $orginalDiv.clone();

    //get original selects into a jq object
    var $originalSelects = $orginalDiv.find('select');

    $clonedDiv.find('select').each(function(index, item) {

        //set new select to value of old select
        $(item).val( $originalSelects.eq(index).val() );

    });

    $clonedDiv.appendTo('clonedItem')
```

WebPage1 Dropdown List

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Priority</p>
    <select name="priority" id="drop1" size="1" onchange="moveTo(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="form2.html">Low</option>
        <option value="form2.html">Normal</option>
        <option value="form2.html">High</option>
       <option value="form2.html">Emergency</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

WebPage2 Dropdown List

```
<div id='clonedItem'>
    <p>Priority</p>
    <select name="priority" id="drop2" size="1">
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Please advise on how to fix this or if there is another way aside from using jquery...Thanks.

Comment: I hope it's a typo, but there is javascript missing from your `moveTo`-function ...

Comment: I don't think javascript can store values, and transfer them between pages (refreshing pages).

Answer (score 0):

Since the page refreshes, you can not store variable is js directly. There are different ways to achieve what you want. If i understand correctly, the two selects are the same, so they have the same options. for this, i would say the "GET" parameter is the most usefull. in your redirect function just add the index of selected option as a GET to the redirect URL:

```
function moveTo(optionValue) {
  if(optionValue=="") return false;
    window.location='http://newURL.com'+"?index="+optionValue;
}
```

Then you just need a js function on the new page which can filter the GET parameter out of the location:

```
function parse(val) {
  var result = "Not found", 
  tmp = [];
  location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function (item) {
    tmp = item.split("=");
    if (tmp[0] === val) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
  });
  return result;
}
```

(see [this aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5448595/3545368) for src)

Then finally call the parse function on pageload on the new page and make the option active:

```
var index = parse(window.location);
$('#drop2 option').eq(index[0]).addClass('selected');
```