# Show & Hide Navigation Menu on certain platform

Tags: javascript, joomla, webview, frontend, navbar

i have question about Menu Showing on website.

So here is my question: 
I maded Android app that pulls website from internet, WebView. So on website there are few caategories when click on some of them the application is going to new Online Web Site (Joomla Web Site in WebView).

So is there any chance when someone is coming from Classic Browser (No android app) to show Nav Bar, But when coming from Android App in WebView to hide Nav Bar.

Thanks

Comment: You could pass a parameter in the URL, like `http://example.com/?navBar=off`, and [take care of that in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

use JavaScript 
navigator.userAgent to identify the client.

or use this http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: What if I'm accessing the site in a regular mobile browser? I assume the navbar should be show in this case.

Comment: there are few options. to modify (spoof) userAgent or add extra header info to identify the app

Comment: Yes navbar should be shown in that case. But in case when somebody use AndroidApp and go to same website the navbar should'nt be shown.