# Retrieve parameter through location.search

Tags: jquery, html

I am sending over a parameter id over to this URL,

```
window.location = "/Payroll/client/index.html#Application.html?id="+applicationId;
```

however when I tried to use:

```
console.log(location.search.substring(1));
```

nothing appeared.

May I know how do I get the parameter from this URL especially when this URL is `index.html#Application.html`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

Comment: that's an improperly formed URL.  As far as the browser is concerned, that "query string" is part of the hash/fragment. hash/fragment component should go after query string component. `window.location = "/Payroll/client/index.html?id="+applicationId+"#Application.html";`

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help. Manage to debug this already.