# HTML form working on web browser but not on mobile devices

Tags: php, html, forms, mobile, html-email

I'm a non-coder or a very new one. I adapted an existing HTML form to work in an email template. There is one field (user email address) and the submit button. When user clicks submit, a php script sends me an email with the data submitted. The thing works fine on Gmail & Outlook on the desktop, but it doesn't work when I am opening the email and clicking on the submit button on a mobile app (e.g. Inbox by gmail, outlook, or spark). The error I get (after being redirected to the mobile browser) is: "You need to submit the form" and a validation error (i.e. that no data was inputted). And while I do receive an email saying that the form is submitted, no data is receieved (even though I have inputted data for sure). Please help!

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$email = $_POST['email'];

//Validate first
if(empty($email)) 
{
    echo "we need your email address for this to work!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'hello@melltoo.me';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Pay&Ship Beta User from Existing Users";
$email_body = "The user $email.\n is responding positively to your email".
    "He/she wants to be a part of beta testing for Pay&Ship ".

$to = "hello@melltoo.me";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?> 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP form to email sample form</title>
<!-- define some style elements-->
<style>
label,a 
{
    font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size : 12px; 
}
/*FORM STYLES*/ 
.tagline-form-object{margin-top:20px;text-align:center}.footer-form-input,
.tagline-form-input{background-color:#FFF;font-size:20px;padding:10px 15px;font-weight:700;color:#555459;border-radius:4px;width:300px;margin-right:10px}
.tagline-form-submit{appearance:none;-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;background-color:#0cb37b;font-size:20px;padding:10px 30px;border-radius:4px;font-weight:700;color:#FFF;text-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);cursor:pointer}
.tagline-form-submit:hover{background-color:#3DA7F2}
.tagline-form-submit:active{border-bottom:1px solid #194BA3;margin-top:1px}

</style>    
<!-- a helper script for vaidating the form-->
<script language="JavaScript" src="scripts/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>


<body>

<!-- Start code for the form-->
<form method="post" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email.php">
            <p>
        <input type="text" class="tagline-form-input" name="email" value="user-email@email.com">
    </p>
    <input class="tagline-form-submit" type="submit" name='submit' value="Add 25 AED to my account!">
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
// Code for validating the form
// Visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml
// for details
var frmvalidator  = new Validator("myemailform");
frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address"); 
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forms in an HTML email have been a risky venture for a long time and still continue today.  It places a security risk that some email clients flat out block interactivity with it (e.g. Outlook) and most others have some sort of warning or limited capability filter on them. ([Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2435/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/))

There is also speculation (but no real solid facts) that HTML forms can reduce deliverability to some ISPs.

It is recommended to send the recipient to a landing page to fill in and submit a form there via their web browser where the security risk is greatly reduced and so are the restrictions and weird behavior that email servers can present.

Also - Why are you submitting a form to collect an email address, when you obviously already have the email address if you are sending them an email. Rather than do a form submit, do a POST or a GET on a landing page with the email address in the parameter of the URL to process your needs. It will remove all user interaction outside a click.

[How to pull parameters from URL using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

[How to submit a form using Javascript](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml)

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that many different email clients will block external resources, like that javascript validator library linked in your example.

Comment: Thanks @gortonington for the answer! I suspect you are right about the email clients blocking the forms (definitely the case with inbox and outlook). I'm actually not collecting email addresses, as you mentioned, I already have them. I am just getting users to agree to do something (beta test our app) and want a low friction way for them to say yes (bright idea: click a button in an email that sends me an email). So I really want to try your suggestion about doing the POST or GET on a landing page, where can I find out more about how to do this? (Again, I'm just a coder-wanna-be).

Comment: The easiest way is if you are using an Email Service Provider (ESP - e.g. Mail Chimp), you turn tracking on to a link or button that says "Yes sign me up!" or whatever and link it to a thank you for signing up page.  You then look at the tracking and all the clicks on that link are your sign ups.  The other option is to use Javascript or a similar script to pull parameters from the URL (e.g. http://url.com/url?e=emailaddress@email.com) and then do a POST to a processing page that inserts it into your data sheet. I would definitely recommend Javascript if you are not going the ESP route.

Comment: edited my answer to include a couple links on how to accomplish the Javascript on your submission page.

Answer (score 0):

What the `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))` does, is basically check if the button was clicked. On a mobile browser; I suspect people will enter their data into the field; and then use the **Go** button on their keyboard to submit it.

This means the form will get posted, but not by pressing the button. If you replace the first line with `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')`, this should at least fix the first error.

For the second error, could you show what `var_dump($_POST);` outputs after submitting the form?

Comment: hi Sjon, thanks for your answer. I tested it myself and clicked the button in the email on the mobile web client. In some cases, a warning message is displayed about the form not working properly due to security constraints. Then I get routed to a browser with the error message that the form has no data. However, I'm increasingly convinced that the form doesn't work due to blocks by the email clients. I'm going to try the suggestion by @Gortonington about doing a POST or GET on a landing page with email address in the URL...if anyone can shed light on that, it would be great!