# Client side redirect using address bar parameters

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm trying to create a redirect page but I need to use two parameters to create the address link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Test file
-->
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=link" />-->
</head>
<body>
<p>Redirecting...</p>
<script language="javascript">
   var chapterx = document.getElementById("chapter").value;
   var linex = document.getElementById("line").value;
   var link = "http://www.mypage.com/help?chapter=" + chapterx + "," + linex;

   //window.prompt(link);
   window.location = link;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm testing this by loading the page from my PC, not from the server.

I have very basic concept about HTML and JS and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I read something from [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page) to create that code.

Plus, theres any way to write the 'link' variable before redirect to see what happen?

Also I have Firebug installed but I cant found the variables that I declared to see their status.

Comment: What should the values of `chapterx` and `linex` be and where do you get them?

Comment: @Lucio both are numbers, parameters in the address bar.

Comment: Then you just need to get them from the URL and not from the DOM. This will help you out since the rest of the code is ok: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5448545/1505348

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. But it will not work because JavaScript detects an error on that line:

```
var chapterx = document.getElementById("chapter").value;
```

You don't have any element on your page with the `chapter` id. Your next line is erroneous too because there is no element on your page with the `line` id.

I added this to your code:

```
<div id="chapter"></div>
<div id="line"></div>
```

after `<p>Redirecting...</p>` and it successfully redirected me to:
http://www.mypage.com/help?chapter=undefined,undefined

Hopefully that helped?:)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, I'm calling something non-existent. I'm trying to set the values that I have in the address bar to create the new address. My old page looks like www.old.com/help.hmtl?chap=1&lin=32 and the new address is www.new.com/help.hmtl?chapter=1,32

Answer (score 0):

Reading the link posted by Lucio I make the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Test file
-->
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=link" />-->
</head>
<body>
<p>Redirecting...</p>
<script language="javascript">
   var chapterx = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.match(/(\?|&)chap\=([^&]*)/)[2]);
   var linex = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.match(/(\?|&)lin\=([^&]*)/)[2]);
   var link = "http://www.myweb.com/help.html?chapter=" + chapterx + "," + linex;
   window.location = link;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```