# How to embed a different web page depending on a query in the URL

Tags: html, url, shiny, embed

I have developed a website in R using shiny. All the code and data is on a server ran by a third party.

On our institution website we have a full page embed of this address to provide a nice permanent URL using this HTML file ...

```
<html> 
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            margin:   0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #iframe1
        {
            height:   100%;
            left:     0px;
            position: absolute;
            top:      0px;
            width:    100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="iframe1" src="http://www.thirdpartyurl.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I have received some requests to add direct links to different parts of the navpage layout of the shiny app, which I have managed to do using `?nav`, e.g. `http://www.thirdpartyurl.com/?nav=Section A` However, I do not know how to adapt the above HTML code (or some other way) so that we can provide a direct link (i.e. embed) for users to the relative section when they use the `http://www.niceurl.com/?nav=Section A` URL?

Answer (score 1):

Use this for the `iframe` (only if you can/are using `php` files)

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="http://www.thirdpartyurl.com/<?php echo !empty($_GET['nav']) ? '?nav=' . $_GET['nav'] : '' ?>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

If that doesn't work see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript) for a `javascript` version to get the `get` attributes.

Comment: Thanks @Thaillie. php does not seem to be an option. I have tried some javascript version...  https://jsfiddle.net/qkfytgLe/1/ but it does not work either. Any ideas? I am clueless when it comes to javascript.