# Set query string parameter as input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

so with jQuery I'd like to take my url value example:

```
/finance-proposal?value=BD07UWT
```

And add it to this input element on my page:

```
<input name="field[21]" id="field21" class="input-text required-entry " style="" value="" type="text"></input>
```

I have tried to parse the url value however I have had no success.

Any idea what would be the most simple method of doing this with jQuery when the page loads?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: There are plugins available for capturing query parameters. Then you'd use `val()` to set the input.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Comment: Use a good URL parsing library. For example, this one: https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl Your current location is stored in window.location.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getParameterByName`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript/901144#901144)([How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript/901144#901144)) to get value from `querystring` provided below. You can assign value using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```js
var getParameterByName = function(name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
  return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
};
var value = getParameterByName('finance-proposal');
$('.input-text required-entry').val(value);
```

Comment: Should give attribution when you copy answers from other questions

Comment: @charlietfl, I agree but `getParameterByName` is used in many of my helpers(though it is taken from some other post) and I do not have the origin of it. If that makes you downvote then  i'm ok with it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1175966

Comment: @charlietfl - Had addd it. Thanks for providing reference :)