# Set up a link to open a page and open a Javascript form?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have a Subscribe form that only opens through Javascript on a link in a page.  It is located at https://pixelark.com/cscc (under 'or signup via email to receive our weekly bulletin. Click here').

The problem is that it requires an extra click for someone to see this subscribe form.  First click to access the page and the second click to access the form.

Is it possilbe to set it up in the a link such that it will goes to the page and open the form automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check for parameters in your URL and in your Document.ready event

something like https://pixelark.com/cscc?page=register or https://pixelark.com/cscc#register

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($('.slider img').length == 2) {
            var global_rotator = setInterval( "rotate()", 5000 );
    }

// insert code here to check location parameters
            });
```

here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript) on how to check location parameters

Answer (score 0):

without using jQuery or something else, add a script tag:

```
<script>
(function() {
  window.onload = function() { show_signup_form('426'); })
})(window);
</script>
```

Comment: i assume you add a script tag on https://pixelark.com/cscc. The problem is that i hvae no control over this page :(.