# angularjs - how to retrieve data from url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have a scenario that I need to get data from URL with `angularjs`. For example:

```
example.com/sampleurl?hk=123
```

I want to get data of variable `hk` which is `123` and use it in my controller. How can I achieve that? So far I tried googled **angularjs http get** but don't seems to get any reference.

Comment: You can inject $routeParams into your controller?

Comment: I didn't understand, you want to get response from server or get value of parameter `hk`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ui-router, you can do like this

```
.state('example', {
  url: 'example/:hk',
  views: {
    'content@': {
      templateUrl: 'example.html',
      controller: 'ExampleController'
    }
  }
});
```

And get back the parameter in your ExampleController by injecting $stateParams

```
angular.module('app').controller('ExampleController', function($stateParams) {
  let hk = $stateParams.hk;
};
```

So for example, when you will reach youapp.com/example/aValue,
hk in the ExampleController will be equal to 'aValue'

Answer (score 1):

Use [$location.search()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

> This method is getter / setter.
>
> Return search part (as object) of current url when called without any parameter.
>
> Change search part when called with parameter and return $location.

Example:

```
var hk = $location.search().hk;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your controller like this :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
...
}
```

Then you can access `$http.get (url, conf)` in your controllers' callback and use `.then` for processing the get response.

[Read the http angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)